# Class constructor unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, class

Before you mark this as a duplicate, I have looked at the other people here on SO with the same error. In fact, I have checked 2 pages of Google until it just started giving me random links and I gave up.

I do not see what the error in my project is. I have changed it around 4-5 times in the ~4 hours I have been working at this. I am already wasting a lot of time just staring at the code hoping to have a revelation but I just cannot focus or there is a different error.

myclass.HPP

```
class MyCLASS {
public:
    __inline MyCLASS(void);

    __inline MyCLASS(scan_t* lpScanInfo);
    __inline MyCLASS(MyCLASS& scanner);

    __inline ~MyCLASS(void);
};
```

myclass.CPP

```
__inline MyCLASS::MyCLASS(void) {

}

__inline MyCLASS::MyCLASS(scan_t* lpScanInfo) {
    performScan(lpScanInfo->hProcess, lpScanInfo->vAddress, lpScanInfo->lpValue, lpScanInfo->lpAllignmentOpt, lpScanInfo->lpValueOpt);
}

__inline MyCLASS::MyCLASS(MyCLASS& scanner) {

}

__inline MyCLASS::~MyCLASS(void) {

}
```

*the inlines were added afterwards while attempting to find a fix

EDIT: Forgot to actually say what and where my error is.

I get the unresolved external symbol ONLY on the         `__inline MyCLASS::MyCLASS(scan_t* lpScanInfo)` constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure what `__inline` is, but why are you trying to apply it to something that seemingly can't be inlined because it's in a different file?

Comment: i don't think that's how it works, but it doesn't really matter since it doesn't fix my problem sadly. any other ideas?

Comment: I assume this is at the linking stage? Did you remember to include this object file when you go to build the executable?

Comment: @Daniel you mean like including myclass.hpp in myclass.cpp? of course. like i said, only one constructor gives me this error for some reason

Comment: @Charles not quite, I mean when you go to link such as `g++ -o program filea.o fileb.o ...` and then you just didn't include myclass.o in your linker step

Comment: Does it work if you remove `__inline`?

Comment: uhh, i'm using an IDE (visual studio) @HolyBlackCat sadly, no

Comment: NEVERMIND guys, it works now. Thanks @HolyBlackCat. I swear the first time I wrote it it had no inline, it gave errors, I added inline, still errors and I assumed if I remove it it won't make a difference, but it did for some reason. Weird

Comment: Are you compiling/building one file at a time or do you have all of these files together in one project? It really seems like you are forgetting to include myclass.o in the linker step so the linker has no idea where the definition of the constructor is

Comment: @Daniel thanks man but if that would have been the case, why would only one definition not be linked? (I have 3 constructors and the deconstructor)

Comment: @Charles it would just depend on the other parts of the code you didn't show. I haven't written a function declaration without a definition in a long time, but I thought the linker may only check if the function definition actually exists if it is explicitly used somewhere. I assumed that was the only version of the constructor that you were using.

Comment: @Daniel Oh I understand what you mean. I get why would think this. Thanks anyway

Comment: Lesson learned: Don't trust your: "make clean"